# django apiview form not showing up

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    audio_file = models.FileField()
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.utcnow)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . import models

class SongSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Song
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from . import models, serializers
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class SongView(APIView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = serializers.SongSerializer(models.Song.objects.all(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

class PostSong(APIView): # The issue <----------------
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        song = request.data.get('song')

        serializer = serializers.SongSerializer(data=song)
        if song.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'OK':'Song Uploaded'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid Data'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('songs/', views.SongView.as_view(), name='songs'),
    path('add-song/', views.PostSong.as_view(), name='add-song')
]
```

> The SongView works perfectly fine and PostSong works too but the form is not showing up, I can only post data via json so I am not able to upload the audio file, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**views.py (CHANGED)**

```
class PostSong(APIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.SongSerializer
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            title = serializer.data.get('title')
            audio_file = serializer.data.get('audio_file')
            genre = serializer.data.get('genre')
            song = models.Song(title=title, audio_file=audio_file, genre=genre)
            return Response(serializers.SongSerializer(song).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response({'Bad Request': 'Invalid Data'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

> Turns out I horribly messed up, this code works!